# What are the ways to generate language server for Xtext based Eclipse plug-in project?

Tags: xtext

We have our own language developed over Xtext. This project is Xtext Project and Eclipse Plug-in.

For this language, we have our own custom Content Assist, error navigation. All these components are configured in UI module of the plugin project.

Can you please help me to understand how these components can be used in Language Server protocol? 
Can configuration in any way(mwe2 or any other way) so that it will use my custom content assist and error navigation in Language server instead of Xtext provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not used at all. All the is used by the language service resides in the mydsl (runtime) and mydsl.ide (eclipse independent ui part) projects.
Thus you have to implement content assist again in the ide project extending https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.ide/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ide/editor/contentassist/IdeContentProposalProvider.xtend
There are plans to unify both extension points https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-eclipse/issues/139

Comment: Do we have any document/blog where it describes custom component creation in Xtext?

Comment: There is the general docs on how to do dependency injection if you mean that

Comment: I have extended IdeContentProposalProvider, but here I need the complete project file access. I need to do my own build and provide my custom integration. Do you have any thought how I can access my complete project?

Comment: Please explain your problem

Comment: I thought it's problem of different context, so created another question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502267/access-of-project-files-in-custom-class-extending-idecontentproposalprovider