# Access of Project Files in custom class extending IdeContentProposalProvider

Tags: xtext

For creating custom content Provider in Xtext, I need to understand all project context. I need to access all other files present in the project/folder.

More Information:

Our Xtext based language have custom completion proposal, error markers. All these components require doing a custom build. For building, we need access to all files and folders present inside our project. ( They have cross-references)

For completion proposal, I have created my own Xtend class in IDE module as:

```
CustomContentProposalProvider extends IdeContentProposalProvider
```

Here, I want to find out all other files present in the folder along with current line and column number and file content.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of behavior? 
Does Xtext provide any approach/API in IDE module which gives projects and it's file content access?

Comment: Ususally not. Can you be more specific on your requirements

Comment: Edited questions with more details.  Kindly let me know if you face any problem in understanding.

Comment: I assume you have to customize the code for that. The proposal provider does not know anything on projects folders etc. it just used the normal scope provider for cross references . I wonder what's so special on your language that normal cross refs don't work

Comment: The language server itself has access to a project view

Comment: You have to digg into the impl

Comment: I have tried to look into it, but no success. Do we have any documentation where it describes Iresource model as of from Eclipse?
Also, any pointer related to this area will be highly helpful.

Comment: I still don't understand your requirement can you please be more explicit

Comment: And there is no itesource model. It's plain Java files . Did you have a look at the projectnanager i pointed you to. It used ifilesystemscsnner